# Securely using a password to login to another Website Flask TM1

Tags: python, security, flask, passwords

I am very new to the secure password topic.
My task is to get a password in a normal form (Flaskform) sending it to the server (https is implemented)
and use the password to login to another Program.

I don't want to store the password, neither do I want the possibility to read out the password on the admin side. My idea is to save the password immediately in the Windows password manager with keyring after getting it in my form. the save function should be called via ajax. After that process, I want to call the TM1 (Tool, which we are using) constructor to login.
Both Tools/Websites are only for internal use but we want to keep them as safe as possible.

My question is:

-Is that a good way to deal with passwords?
-Are there better ways?
(-Is there a way to get the hashed passwords from TM1)

My first Prototype (only for the keyring thing) looks like that:

```
import configparser
from getpass import getpass
import keyring
from TM1py import TM1Service

INSTANCE = "xxxx"
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

address = config[INSTANCE]["address"]
port = config[INSTANCE]["port"]
ssl = config[INSTANCE]["ssl"]
user = config[INSTANCE]["user"]

# interact with Windows Credential Manager through the keyring library
password = keyring.get_password(INSTANCE, user)
if not password:
    password = getpass(f"Please insert password for user '{user}' and instance '{INSTANCE}':")
keyring.set_password(INSTANCE, user, password)

with TM1Service(**config[INSTANCE]) as tm1:
    tm1_version = tm1.server.get_product_version()
    print(tm1_version)

with TM1Service(address=address, port=port, user=user, password=password,gateway=gateway, namespace=namespace, ssl=ssl) as tm1:
    serverName = tm1.server.get_server_name()
    print("Connection to TM1 established!! your Servername is: {}".format(serverName))
```

Comment: Check if you can make the backend server to understand login via oAuth. Then you would not need any password but just store some generated tokens for each user and the token can only be used for accessing this service.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer! 
It actually helped me a lot.
Unfortunately my chef doesn't want to give me the url of the API so i am not able to use oAuth..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the technic explain  at the end of this post ?

```
https://code.cubewise.com/blog/mastering-the-tm1-rest-api-with-postman
```

with No Auth ??
I let you check it.
If your chief don't want to give you the API URL i don't see how you can make it happen.
May you could try to connection you directly to a admin server (the windows service) of tm1 so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
i looked at the solution and discussed it with my chef.
In his understanding Postman only works if u install it right? 
I guess in the end he will decide to use his solution to use session variables to get the passwords and save them temporally.

Comment: Yes postman works only if its intalled. It was an example to show you how you can have other way to authentificate a user to TM1/Planning Analytics.